# Pdf file is not updating in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

In my asp.net application we generating pdf using ITextSharp.dll
Now my problem is every time same pdf is opening(not refreshing) unless until clear my browser history it is same. I am using chrome browser.

Here is my code

```
private void fillForm() {
    try {
        string Phone = "", Physical = "";
        string formFile = Server.MapPath("~\\Inspection.pdf");
        string newFile = Server.MapPath("~\\InspectionPrint.pdf");
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
        PdfContentByte d = new PdfContentByte(stamper.Writer);
        //getting values from DB
        SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("usp_PrintInspection", QMSConn);
        QMSConn.Open();
        comd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comd.Parameters.Add("@QuoteNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comd.Parameters["@QuoteNumber"].Value = Session["CurrQuoteNumber"].ToString();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = comd;
        sqlAdapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
            // set form fields
            string Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString();
            string Address1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address1"].ToString();
            string CompanyID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CompanyID"].ToString();
            string PolicyNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PolicyNumber"].ToString();

            fields.SetField("Name", Name);
            fields.SetField("Address1", Address1);
            fields.SetField("CompanyID ", CompanyID);
            fields.SetField("PolicyNumber", PolicyNumber);

            stamper.FormFlattening = false;
            stamper.Close();

            string file = "InspectionPrint";

            string Url = "../" + file + ".pdf";
            String js = @"WindowPopup('" + Url + "');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Key", js, true);
        }
        else {
            showalert("No Record Available For This Quote");
        }
    }
    catch(exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share us the code?

Comment: I have added my code.. pls look into it and let me know what was the issue.

Comment: This is in production server only in local its working fine. and one more thing in production iis is upgrade to iis6 to iis7.5.. Is any effect with that?

Comment: i have never used ITextSharp but from your code what i understood is - you are taking input file `Inspection.pdf` and writing the contents of it into `InspectionPrint.pdf`. after all you are opening the dialog to show the `InspectionPrint` file am i right?

Answer (score 0):

as you are saying it is working in the Localhost but not in the production server, most likely it seems to me as an `URL/Path` issue.

**1.**  after observing your code, you are creating one more string `Url` variable without using the existing String `formFile` variable.

as you should provide the `valid path` you need to use the `formFile` instead of `Url` as you have created `formFile` using `Server.MapPath()`

Try This:

```
/*string Url = "../" + file + ".pdf";*/ //comment or remove
String js = @"WindowPopup('" + formFile + "');";//use formFile instead of Url
```

Comment: When I try this nothing is displaying, out put is blank page...             Please let me know what is the exact problem